# how can we initialize a vector with all values 0 in C++

Tags: c++, vector, stl, initialization, memset

In an array we can do
`int arr[100]={0}` ,this initializes all the values in the array to 0.
I was trying the same with vector like
`vector <int> v(100)={0}` ,but its giving the error
`error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘=’ token`. Also if we can do this by "memset" function of C++ please tell that solution also.

Comment: Common misunderstanding about the array: you don't need to have `{0}`, people think that _that's_ the value used, as if writing `{5}` will construct them all to `5`. Just writing `int arr[100] = {};` will default construct them to `0`, providing a single value will construct the first value to that, and the rest to `0`

Comment: Perhaps a [`std::vector` constructor reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) might be helpful?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use:

```
std::vector<int> v(100); // 100 is the number of elements.
                         // The elements are initialized with zero values.
```

You can be explicit about the zero values by using:

```
std::vector<int> v(100, 0);
```

You can use the second form to initialize all the elements to something other than zero.

```
std::vector<int> v(100, 5); // Creates object with 100 elements.
                            // Each of the elements is initialized to 5
```